# Facebook messenger chatbot deploying error

Tags: python, heroku

I created a facebook messenger chatbot and followed all steps in creation,
I need to use Python version 3.6.6 or above. I have edited the requirement file to python==3.6.6 instead of python2.7.15, then I got the following:

When I am deploying the app to HEROKU I got this error :

[image]

how to solve this issue ??

Comment: Can you edit, what commands are you using to call the program, maybe try something like "ptyhon3 myapp.py" to use python3!

Comment: The problem was solved, thank you .. I used a library for python2 while I was using python3 ..
Thanks for your help